# Select not working inside Conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

When inserting this option selector in React appears on the screen correctly:

```
render() {

    return (
      <div>
       <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
       </select>
      </div>
  )};
```

When I put the same in a conditional, it does not appear (everything else appears in the conditional)

```
render() {

    return (
      <div>
       {this.state.options ? 
        <select>
         <option>A</option>
         <option>B</option>
         <option>C</option>
        </select>
       :
       <p>A</p>
      }
     </div>
  )};
```

Some explanation?

Comment: If "this.state.options" is null, only "<p>A</p>" will show up. What do you have in your state, or what is your initial state?

Comment: Try checking the value of "this.state.options", because there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: this.state.options is working. If I put anything else within that condition it does appear, but the select never appears

Comment: Try replacing "true" in place of "this.state.options", you will get to see it. You can also check the type of this.state.options, it should be a boolean value. Please show us the initial value of "this.state.options".

Comment: Okk!! Replacing "true" in place of "this.state.options" it Works. How is it possible if in any case it paints everything in the first condition (this.state.options) except the select??